# Eclipse: How to support older Android Versions?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to Support all Android Versions, that exists? How does that work in Eclipse?

Comment: In your Manifest file, set the `minSdkVersion` to **8** (for instance). And add the support libraries (including the appcompat library).

Comment: How to add the Support libraries?

Comment: For this, use google.

Comment: @DerGolem I have a feeling he doesn't want to use Google search. He wouldn't be here asking this if he did.

Comment: Have you considered using Android Studio instead of Eclipse? The transition is very easy and it is a way better IDE for Android.

Comment: FYI: Google will probably stop the Eclipse Android plugin soon, they announced this somewhere this week. So my suggestion would be to use Android Studio from now on either way

Comment: I thought it's much easier to ask here. I googled a Little bit, but it wasn't that helpful- But I think I have to use the Android SDK Manager. But in the SDK Manager, it jumps from API15 to API10...

Comment: Use AppCompat support library to support UI from SDK 7 till latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that, but you will probably eventually choose not to. Because in the older versions, you don't have all possibilities you now have in the latest version of Android. The API in older versions is very limited.

If you want to do that, you could just use the minSdkVersion in your manifest, that will set the minimal Android version you need to have to run the app.

I suggest you have a look at the following site http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

Edit: You only need to download the Android version you are locally building against. For example if you say your minSdkVersion is 11, but you're locally building with version 15, that's perfectly okay. You don't need to do anything else for supporting the previous versions. Of course you will need the support libraries too.

Comment: In my manifest I have this: android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="21". But I thought I have to download the older libraries in Android SDK Manager, too?!

Comment: Updated my answer a little. Next time, make sure you ask all the information you need in your original question. So we can answer to the point.

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="21" is the same like API21, am I right? Because then I have to Change the 21 to 22 in my manifest. Because 22 is the newest?!

Comment: Yes, more information about the SDK versions you can find here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html